# How to convert dates likes this 2020-11-08T12:33:01.982826+01:00 to DD/MM/YY or 2 days ago or 4 hours ago like that in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Hello all How to convert dates likes this `2020-11-08T12:33:01.982826+01:00` to `DD/MM/YY` or `2 days ago` or `4 hours ago` or in `HH:MM` in react? I am getting the dates in this format from the backend and want to atleast show it in a more concise way.

Thanks

Comment: Use moment.js, or write some code.

Comment: Ok.Thank you. I will check moment.js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat was a very short search away.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for the link, I tried that before, but it was showing an error for me. I will check that again.

Comment: “An error for me” - showing your effort with this is much better than asking “how can I”

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented using js

```
function sayHello() {
    var res;
    setInterval( function (){
        var startDateTime = new Date("2020-11-08T12:33:01.982826+01:00");
        var startStamp = startDateTime.getTime();
        newDate = new Date();
        newStamp = newDate.getTime();
        var diff = Math.round((newStamp - startStamp) / 1000);
        var h = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60));
        diff = diff - (h * 60 * 60);
        var m = Math.floor(diff / (60));
        diff = diff - (m * 60);
        var s = diff;
        if (h > 0)
        {
            res=h+"hrs"+m+"min ago"
            console.log(res)
        } else if (m > 0)
        {
            res=m+"min ago";
            console.log(res)

        } else
        {
            res=s+"sec ago"
            console.log(res)

        }

    },1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a popular library for formatting dates and time like date-fns for example.

```
const d = format(new Date("2020-11-08T12:33:01.982826+01:00"), "dd/MM/yy");

console.log(d); // 08/11/20

formatDistance(subDays(new Date(), 3), new Date())
//=> "3 days ago"
```

Please, refer to [the docs](https://date-fns.org/).